# The probability that a Brownian bridge is a Brownian excursion

Tags: simulation, brownian-motion

```
bb <- function() {
y <<- c(0,sort(runif(9999)),1)
x <<- seq(0,10000)/10000
y <<- y-x
}
plot(x,y,type="l",asp=30)
abline(h=0)
```

The R code above shows you the graph of a Brownian bridge – a random function whose probability distribution is the conditional distribution of a Wiener process given that its value at $1$ (and of course at $0$) is $0.$ (Its variance at any $x$ value is $\text{constant} \times x(1-x).$ I have not attempted to make the constant equal to $1$ or to anything else in particular since that won't matter here.)

```
count <- 0
for(k in seq(100000)) {
bb()
if (min(y[seq(2,10000)]) * max(y[seq(2,10000)]) > 0) count <<- count + 1
}
```

The loop above increments the count every time the Brownian bridge stays on one side of the $x$-axis, so that it starts and ends at $0$ and does not return to $0$ until the end. Thus it is a Brownian excursion.

I've run this several times, getting counts in the low-to-mid 20s. Thus an estimate of the probability that a Brownian bridge is a Brownian excursion is around $0.00022.$

Is there a closed form for this probability?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The closed form is 0.

That is, for a true Brownian bridge, the probability of being a Brownian excursion is zero. With probability 1, a Brownian bridge has additional zeroes near $t=0$ and $t=1$. In fact, [with probability 1 it has infinitely many additional zeroes](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3098741/proof-that-a-standard-brownian-motion-visits-zero-infinitely-often-at-the-beginn)

For a discrete approximation to a Brownian Bridge the answer will depend on how you approximate -- eg using a finite-sample empirical CDF as here, or using a discrete-time Gaussian random walk.